# Display data in tabular format in jsp

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl, el

I am trying the following jsp code.

```
    switch(ch)            
    {
    case 1 : 
        ResultSet rsid=stmt.executeQuery("select ID from BcTwo"); 
        while(rsid.next())
        {
        %>  
            <tr><td>
              <%out.println(rsid.getString(1)); %>
            </td></tr>
             <% 
         }
         rsid.close();
         break;
    case 2 : 
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select SERIES from BcTwo");  
        while(rs.next())
        {
        %>  
            <tr><td>
            <%out.println(rs.getString("SERIES")); %>
            </td></tr>
            <%  
        }
        rs.close();
        break;
    }
```

Using this code I am able to print the data.But I want the data to be printed in following format :

```
ID  Series
1   BE
2   EQ
3   BE
4   BE
5   EQ
6   EQ
```

And using the above code data is getting printed as :

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
Series
BE
EQ
BE
BE
EQ
EQ
```

What changes I should make to get the required output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
switch(ch)            
{
    case 1 :
        String  ID=(String)session.getAttribute("ID");
          session.setAttribute("ID", ID); 
          if(null == session.getAttribute("ID"))
          { 
          out.println(rsid.getString("ID"));
          } 
          break;
    case 2 :
        String  SERIES=(String)session.getAttribute("SERIES");
        session.setAttribute("SERIES", SERIES); 
        if(null == session.getAttribute("SERIES"))
        { 
        out.println(rsid.getString("SERIES"));
        }  
         break;
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the best solution but it just worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(ch)            
    {
 %>
 <tr>
 <%
    case 1 : 
        ResultSet rsid=stmt.executeQuery("select ID from BcTwo"); 
          while(rsid.next())
        {
        %>  
            <td>
              <%out.print(rsid.getString(1)); %>
            </td>
              <%    
          }
          rsid.close();
        break;
    case 2 : 
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select SERIES from BcTwo");  
          while(rs.next())
        {
        %>  
            <td>
            <%out.print(rs.getString("SERIES")); %>
            </td>
            <%  
          }
          rs.close();
        break;
    }
    %>
    </tr>
```

Comment: and what is this switch statement for ?

Comment: There are 6 columns in my table . I want to display data only for those columns which are selected by user using checkbox. The switch case is used to know which check boxes are selected by user.

Comment: then you should do it someother way e.g. create a String based on the checkboxes selected and then execute it to get the results and print it accordingly like case 1 : ID_SELECT = true ; break ; and then after switch create a StringBulider and keep appending column names to it based upon the boolean results and at end convert it into string

Answer (score 1):

first of all ,having java code inside scriptlets is a bad practice. You should avoid it. DO the necessary java code in a servlet and use EL or JSTL to display the returned data in the JSP

as for your question, each result will have a TR where the ID and SERIES will be printed inside that TR in 2 TDs

```
   <%
      ResultSet rsid=stmt.executeQuery("select ID,SERIES from BcTwo"); 
      while(rsid.next())
      {
    %>  
    <tr>
        <td>
          <%out.print(rsid.getString("ID")); %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%out.print(rsid.getString("SERIES")); %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%    
      }
      rsid.close();
    %>
```

hope this helps..

Comment: :The above code is working. But I have to write the code in switch case. Because ID, SERIES are the fields selected by user using check box.

Comment: than pass these user parameters to a controller and execute a single parameter based jdbc query to get results and populate the jsp using those data..